# XRegExp no look-behind?

Tags: javascript, regex, xregexp

I need to use lookbehind of regex in JavaScript, so found
[Simulating lookbehind in JavaScript (take 2)](https://gist.github.com/slevithan/2387872).
Also, I found the author Steven Levithan is the one who developed [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/).

I git cloned [XRegExp 3.0.0-pre](https://github.com/slevithan/xregexp), and tested

some lookbehind logic
http://regex101.com/r/xD0xZ5
using XRegExp

```
var XRegExp = require('xregexp');
console.log(XRegExp.replace('foobar', '(?<=foo)bar', 'test'));
```

It seems not working;

```
$ node test
foobar
```

What do I miss? Thanks.

EDIT:
My goal is something like

```
(?<=foo)[\s\S]+(?=bar)
```

http://regex101.com/r/sV5gD5

(EDIT2 the link was wrong and modifed)

**Answer:**

```
var str = "fooanythingbar";
console.log(str);
console.log(str.replace(/(foo)(?:[\s\S]+(?=bar))/g, '$1test'));

//footestbar
```

Credit goes to @Trevor Senior Thanks!

Comment: Everything is working fine in the link you gave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use [non-capturing groups](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-non-capturing-parentheses) for this, e.g.

```js
$ node
> 'foobar'.replace(/(foo)(?:bar)/g, '$1test')
'footest'
```

In the second parameter of [String.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), the special notation of `$1` references the first capturing group, which is `(foo)` in this case. By using `$1test`, one can think of `$1` as a placeholder for the first matching group. When expanded, this becomes `'footest'`.

For more in depth details on the regular expression, [view what it matches here](http://regex101.com/r/zO6nQ8).

Comment: Thanks Trevor Senior; however, What I'd like is lookbehind logic: for a given 'foobar'  -> 'footest'

Comment: I've edited my answer, but I may be missing the question. This may be a little confusing if you're new to non-capturing groups. Basically we're replacing the entire match with `'test'`, but then bringing back in a matching group denoted by `$1`.

Comment: Thanks for your concise input. @Trevor Senior . I understand, Please see my Edit or Q

Answer (score 4):

I want to give an update on the state of affairs.

> Lookahead assertions have been part of JavaScript’s regular expression
>   syntax from the start. Their counterpart, lookbehind assertions, are
>   finally being [introduced](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-lookbehind) ... *in Google Chrome 62
>   Source: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/07/upcoming-regexp-features

If you run this in with [Chrome 62+, v8 6.2.414](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome_version_history) you will get the expected result: `footest`
- independent of [XRegex](https://github.com/slevithan/xregexp)!

```js
 
var x = XRegExp('(?<=foo)bar', 'g');
console.log(XRegExp.replace('foobar', x, 'test'));

console.log("foobar".replace( new RegExp('(?<=foo)bar',"g"),"test"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/xregexp/xregexp-all.js"></script>
```

However, no other browser supports lookbehind assertions yet - not even node.js, which is based on v8 (tested with [node v9.7.1/v8 6.2.414.46](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/), but I expect it will be added in upcoming node releases.)

Hopefully, other vendors will follow soon.