# regex complicated scenario during the text of markdown

Tags: javascript, regex

Given a Markdown source text:

```
- sometext

- sometext
followingText



- sometext

- sometext
- sometext
```

I want to replace double newlines `\n\n` to `\nWhiteSpace\n` among the List range;

so with [$1 technique of JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18156794/xregexp-no-look-behind), I did

`(- [\s\S]+?)(?:\n\n(?=\n))|(- [\s\S]+?)(?:\n\n(?=- ))`
http://regex101.com/r/hO7vT9

The blue selection is the target where almost working, except the very first double newlines are failed to be selected.

This is because `(- [\s\S]+?)(?:\n\n(?=\n))` matches first and the `(- [\s\S]+?)(?:\n\n(?=- ))` is not evaluated.

Sure, I can revert the order `(- [\s\S]+?)(?:\n\n(?=- ))|(- [\s\S]+?)(?:\n\n(?=\n))`,
then now

http://regex101.com/r/tR8sN4

Now, the first selection works, but the second selection failes.(compare to the first version, the intended result for the second selection).

Is there any work-around for this?

Of course, you may suggest separate the regex, and replace twice; well I did, and the result is messy, so I would like achieve this in a single regex. The language is JS.

Comment: I am sorry if I completely misunderstood your question, but is [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/xLhqR/) what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks, Harry. Well, no. For some technical reason, the double new line must be within the specific list structure context.

Comment: Are you parsing markdown?  You probably shouldn't be using regular expressions for this.  Have you considered parsing line-by-line and using regular expressions on each line separately?

Comment: That is fine. I have updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/xLhqR/) now. My last attempt, check and if this is also not what you want, I quit :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting my comment as an answer.

Try the below. Sorry, if this is still not what you want.

```
regex = new RegExp(/(- [\s\S]+?)(?:(\n){2,}(?=\n|-))/g);
inputString = '- sometext\n\n- sometext\nfollowingText\n\n\n\n- sometext\n\n- sometext\n- sometext';
outputString = inputString.replace(regex,'$1\nWhiteSpace\n');
console.log(outputString);
```

Comment: Thanks, Harry. actually, I gave up what I was doing. In fact, I tried to hack marks for my own extension, but too complicated, so I shall start from scrach by my own. anyway Check +1 for your kind contribution. Appreciated